# Unity: Download a part of a txt file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a long txt file and I only have to download the very last 6 lines of it.

Right now I'm using www:

```
private IEnumerator doStuff()
{
    WWW www = new WWW ("http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt");
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log (www.text);
}
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. You have to download the complete file. Do you have control over the server and the code that runs on the server?

Comment: No. I'm downloading a file from dropbox and therefore just have access to the data.

Comment: Then you can't. You need a server or rented one in order to do that. Any one that claims you can do this is lying to you unless the API from that sites supports it. **You can't**.

Comment: That's not the answer I was looking for, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Yup, It will download everything. You are welcome!